# How do I create a working emulator in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've tried to run my project in the emulator (virtual) but an error occurred. 
It's my first run in the emulator.

```
12:37   Emulator: WARNING: unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.

12:37   Emulator: Unexpected feature list: Mac80211hwsimUserspaceManaged MultiDisplay Vulkan VulkanIgnoredHandles VulkanNullOptionalStrings YUVCache

12:38   Failed to commit install session 979912577 with command cmd package install-commit 979912577. Error: Unknown failure: cmd: Failure calling service package: Broken pipe (32)

12:38   Session 'app': Error Installing APKs

12:38   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Update the emulator

Comment: Thank's, it works fine

Comment: in your stacktrace first string contains message for you "please try updating the emulator". or easier to ask instead of read?

Comment: Hi, I said you in comments that "Update the emulator", but you check your answer as correct one

Comment: Yes, I did it because your answer was later than mine. I can't check a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe problem is that your emulator isn't updated, update it.

Answer (score 0):

Updating everything works fine